# How do you cite some commonly circulated image on the Internet with no source

Tags: citations

Pretend that there is some image on the Internet that is commonly circulated, like a meme template involving a picture of someone's face. If the original thing had no source, but one (for whatever reason) needed the image and its citation, how would one try to cite the image?

Answer (score 3):

I would cite such a source in the same way as an *anonymous* or *unknown* author's work would be cited. You should consult whatever style guide you're using for your current manuscript.

Comment: I'd do this but include a web address (including access time) where the image can be retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

A citation does not need to point to the original source of the material; just a sufficiently authoritative reference. For instance, if you cite a mathematical result that dates back to the 18th century you can cite a textbook, not the original source where it appeared.

In this case, you can cite the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_phenomena) of the meme if it has one, or something like [knowyourmeme.com](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/o-rly) (warning: possible time sink).